# difference between context.xml and server.xml?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

what is the difference between `context.xml` of Tomcat and `server.xml` of Tomcat ? If I want to add a tag like :

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/MyDs" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
     url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/my_database;create=true"
     username="me" password="me" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

where should I add it ?

Comment: Perhaps you can [check this link.](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-context)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The server.xml is used for server and context.xml is for application that runs on that server. There may be several context.xml files (per application) on a server but only one server.xml.

Comment: can I add the mentioned tag in either of the xml ?

Comment: It seems something related to application, so I reccommend adding it to context.xml

Comment: Will I commit a mistake if I put it inside the server.xml?

Comment: While you could put some stuff in server.xml, I would still recomend  only putting server wide settings in there (ports, pool sizes, etc...).  Anything app specific should be put in an individual context file.

Comment: @Matt I have only one `context.xml` file in the `conf` folder of tomcat. Are there seperate xml files for each application ? I have 2 projects based upon tomcat. [But I see only 1 context.xml file in the conf folder .](http://i49.tinypic.com/344beva.jpg)

Answer (score 16):

Tomcat web application has a bunch of configs called deployment descriptors which can be separated in two groups: server-dependent (context.xml) and server-independent (web.xml).

**server.xml** - stores on server side and describe the general configuration of Tomcat server. This file is the only one for a one Tomcat server.

**context.xml** - can be stored on server side (conf/) or be embedded in a web app (META-INF/). This file contains server-dependent configuration like DataSources provided by Tomcat server.

**web.xml** -  can be stored on server side (conf/) or be embedded in a web app (WEB-INF/). This file contains server-independent configuration like servlet mappings.

Context.xml and web.xml on a server-side in the Tomcat conf/ directory are used to provide the default behavior of Tomcat, like default servlet mappings. Thus we have one server.xml per server and a pair context.xml/web.xml of files per a web application. If you want to share configuration between several application you should use server.xml (e.g. like it is for security Realms). Otherwise - server.xml/web.xml. In your case I suggest you to use web app embedded context.xml.

Comment: In the last two sentences, you say that "Otherwise - server.xml/web.xml."  Is it supposed to be edited to "context.xml/web.xml" Or keep it as "server.xml/web.xml?"

Answer (score 2):

This entry can go in server.xml under  or in individual context files.  Context xml files can be specific to each application deployment, whereas server.xml becomes global.

Application specific context files are usually located in catalina\localhost folder.